# Apache Camel: interceptFrom: Can the transaction started in interceptFrom be shared in main route?

Tags: transactions, apache-camel, spring-transactions, intercept

I have below **code sample** where I am calling a direct **transacted** route from "**interceptFrom**" of InputQueue route (main route). Here, main route is also **transacted**.

When running this, I can see from the log that a transaction is being started and committed in interceptFrom, while in main route another transaction is starting and getting committed.

**My requirement is, I need to have a single transaction which should cover both fromIntercept and main route processing as I am doing some DB operations in fromIntercept and want it to rollback in case any exception happens in main route.** Below is the log:

```
@Component
public class DemoTransactionRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoTransactionRoute.class);
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        final String FROM_INTERCEPT_ROUTE = "direct://demoFromInterceptor";

        interceptFrom("activemq:*")
                .to(FROM_INTERCEPT_ROUTE);

        from(FROM_INTERCEPT_ROUTE)
                .routeId(FROM_INTERCEPT_ROUTE)
                .transacted("JPA_TRANSACTION") // defined in service xml
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger, "Inside From Interceptor");


        from("activemq:queue:InputQueue")
                .routeId("activemq:queue:InputQueue")
                .transacted("JPA_TRANSACTION") // defined in service xml
                .log("On service route");
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
2020-05-28 12:09:06.742 DEBUG 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener      : Received Message has JMSCorrelationID []
2020-05-28 12:09:06.785 DEBUG 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] o.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor   : >>>> direct://demoFromInterceptor Exchange[ID-XYZA-Z123456-1590631725657-0-1]
2020-05-28 12:09:06.787 DEBUG 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction begin (0x78d9f51b) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID:XYZA-Z123456-52145-1590554620554-4:5:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-XYZA-Z123456-1590631725657-0-1))
2020-05-28 12:09:06.792  INFO 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] c.c.c.routes.DemoTransactionRoute        : Inside From Interceptor
2020-05-28 12:09:06.793 DEBUG 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction commit (0x78d9f51b) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID:XYZA-Z123456-52145-1590554620554-4:5:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-XYZA-Z123456-1590631725657-0-1))
2020-05-28 12:09:06.793 DEBUG 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction begin (0x78d9f51b) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID:XYZA-Z123456-52145-1590554620554-4:5:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-XYZA-Z123456-1590631725657-0-1))
2020-05-28 12:09:06.793  INFO 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] activemq:queue:InputQueue                : On service route
2020-05-28 12:09:06.793 DEBUG 15936 --- [mer[InputQueue]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction commit (0x78d9f51b) redelivered(false) for (MessageId: ID:XYZA-Z123456-52145-1590554620554-4:5:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-XYZA-Z123456-1590631725657-0-1))
```